# Accept Only GMail Emails In Forms

Tags: php, forms, email

I have form here and I would like to accept only GMail Email address.

This is the part of the form.

```
function is_email($email){
   $x = '\d\w!\#\$%&\'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~';    //just for clarity

   return count($email = explode('@', $email, 3)) == 2
       && strlen($email[0]) < 65
       && strlen($email[1]) < 256
       && preg_match("#^[$x]+(\.?([$x]+\.)*[$x]+)?$#", $email[0])
       && preg_match('#^(([a-z0-9]+-*)?[a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}.?$#', $email[1]);
}


    elseif (!is_email($Email)) {
        $resultado = "Please, use a valid email address. (Required for account activation)<br><br> <a href=javascript:history.go(-1)>Go back!</a>";
    }
```

I already tried "explode ('@gmail.com', $email, 3)) == 2" but get me some error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if the string ends with "@gmail.com":

```
/**
 * Check if an email is a Gmail address
 * @param string $email The email address to check
 * @return boolean
 */
function isGmail($email) {
    $email = trim($email); // in case there's any whitespace

    return mb_substr($email, -10) === '@gmail.com';
}
```

I'm using [`mb_substr`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) here but alternatively you can use [`substr`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: I'm not sure what you current code is doing but my function doesn't check if the string is a valid email address, only if it ends with `@gmail.com`. You can use [Filter functions](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) to validate an email if necessary.

Comment: I tried to replace it with this but when submitting the form it doesn't return any message neither an email is received.

Comment: This function returns true or false so your code should look for a true/false value when running the address through this function.

Comment: Btw, what if I will add Hotmail and Outlook email address?

Comment: You can add disjunctive conditions in the return statement: `return mb_substr($email, -10) === '@gmail.com' || mb_substr($email, -12) === '@hotmail.com' || mb_substr($email, -12) === '@outlook.com';` However, if there's a lot of domains you want checked then having them in an array is more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

check for condition:

```
preg_match("~@gmail\.com$~",$email)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validgmail($email) {
// do other checkings

if (substr($email, 0, -10) == "@gmail.com")
{

// it's valid email

} else {
  //invalid

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method working

```
$email = 'mrshahbaznns@gmail.com';
        if(preg_match("~@gmail\.com$~",$email)){
        echo 'good';
    }
    else{
        echo 'bad';
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)