# Allow only mails with @gmail.com ending

Tags: php

This [Github repository](https://github.com/TuberBoy/DotMailsGenerator-PHP/blob/main/index.php) serves to add a dot (.) to a Gmail address and thus register on a site multiple times with random addresses derived from the original.

The code works fine, but it works with any domain (e.g. @house.com)

And I need to limit it to only work with @gmail.com (I tried this in my HTML) `<input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@gmail\.com$">`

But I prefer it to be server side, I have no idea how to do it, I am new in PHP.

Thanks in advance.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    echo '<div class="box"><div class="title">Total: '.sizeof($res).'</div><textarea type="text">';
    foreach($res as $mcMails)
    {
        echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</textarea></div>';
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with

Comment: You don't need both ltrim and rtrim. `trim` will trim from both sides of the string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174308/accept-only-gmail-emails-in-forms

Comment: @Shozabjaveed i cant adapt to my code with the first and second answers, you can help me? :(

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 8+ you can use [str_ends_with()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with).

```
function isGmail($email) {
    return str_ends_with($email, '@gmail.com');
}
```

Or a prior PHP8+ with a classic regex

```
function isGmail($email) {
    return preg_match("/@gmail.com\$/", $email);
}
```

or strpos with a negative offset

```
function isGmail($email) {
    $pattern = '@gmail.com';
    return (false !== strpos($email, $pattern, -strlen($pattern)));
}
```

### Update

Regarding from your comment I think you want to do something like this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'] ?? '';
if(!isGmail($email)) {
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I cant :( the script still generating others @example.com emails

Comment: but thank you, i'll keep trying u.u

Comment: You can not what? The function tests for ending @gmail.com what is your question about. Else you need to declare your request more precisely.

Comment: My idea was that if the email does not end in @gmail.com the script would stop and send me to the index again.

Comment: You can just implement that logic with a simple if condition. Look at my answer, again. I've added an update.

Comment: Thank you so much! your answers and other answers work for me, ill put the final code here.

Comment: No, please do not change your question as it answered. You can mark the answer "as correct".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    if(isGmail($_POST['email'])){
     $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
     $email = $mail[0];
     $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
     $email = ltrim($email);
     $domain = ltrim($domain);
     $email = rtrim($email);
     $domain = rtrim($domain);
     $email = stripslashes($email);
     $domain = stripslashes($domain);
     $email = htmlentities($email);
     $domain = htmlentities($domain);
     $res = addDOT($email);
     echo '<div class="box"><div class="title">Total:'.sizeof($res).'</div><textarea type="text">';
       foreach($res as $mcMails)
      {
        echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
      }
      echo '</textarea></div>';
  }
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
/**
 * Check if an email is a Gmail address
 * @param string $email The email address to check
 * @return boolean
 */
function isGmail($email) {
    $email = trim($email); // in case there's any whitespace

    return mb_substr($email, -10) === '@gmail.com';
}
?>
```

Comment: I put it as is and it still generates emails even though they do not end in @gmail.com :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I modified the first if of the code by putting a second conditional:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) and (substr($_POST['email'], -10) == '@gmail.com'))
```